# Returning multiple rows with a function

Tags: sql, oracle, function, cursor

While calling the function below, i get only the last row of all the rows that is returned by the cursor. It is important that I use cursor in this statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnc_get_contractor_id(cst_username IN VARCHAR2 )
    RETURN NUMBER
    AS

    CURSOR cursor_contract_name IS
    SELECT plc.FK2_CONTRACTOR_ID
        FROM lds_consultant cons
        INNER JOIN lds_account acc on cons.consultant_id = acc.fk1_consultant_id 
        INNER JOIN lds_placement plc on acc.account_id = plc.FK1_ACCOUNT_ID
        WHERE UPPER(cons.USERNAME) = UPPER(cst_username)
        AND UPPER(plc.PLT_TO_PERMANENT) = UPPER('Y');

    V_contracotr_id number(10);

    BEGIN

    for rec in cursor_contract_name loop

      V_contracotr_id := rec.fk2_contractor_id;

      dbms_output.put_line('cst_username : '||cst_username||'  V_contracotr_id :'||V_contracotr_id);

            --return V_contracotr_id;

            END LOOP;

                    return V_contracotr_id;
    END;
    /
```

how could i return all the rows so that i can create a table using the returned rows?

Comment: Your function returns a single number.  If you want to return multiple "rows" of values, you need to return a table or a cursor.

Comment: How could I define the return type in that case?

Comment: . . Defining such a function involves more than declaring the return type.  Start with the Oracle documentation on `CREATE FUNCTION`.

Comment: could you please take a look this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37288595/inconsistent-datatypes-when-returning-table-from-cursor-in-a-package-function?noredirect=1#comment62102603_37288595