# inconsistent datatypes: when returning table from cursor in a package function - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, function, package

I have the following package. I am trying to fill the records inside the function from a cursor and return the record. I am unsure of how to assign the rows from the cursor into the record variable. I need to return the record so that I could create a materialized view from it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_contrator_of_consultant AS

    TYPE cst_record IS RECORD(
       consultant_id NUMBER(10));

    TYPE cst_id_type IS TABLE OF cst_record;

    FUNCTION fnc_get_contractor_id(cst_username IN VARCHAR2)
        RETURN cst_id_type
        PIPELINED;
END;


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_contrator_of_consultant AS 

    FUNCTION fnc_get_contractor_id(cst_username IN VARCHAR2 )
        RETURN cst_id_type
        PIPELINED IS    

        V_cursor_contracotr_id cst_id_type;

        CURSOR cursor_contract_name IS
        SELECT plc.FK2_CONTRACTOR_ID
            FROM lds_consultant cons
            INNER JOIN lds_account acc on cons.consultant_id = acc.fk1_consultant_id 
            INNER JOIN lds_placement plc on acc.account_id = plc.FK1_ACCOUNT_ID
            WHERE UPPER(cons.USERNAME) = UPPER(cst_username)
            AND UPPER(plc.PLT_TO_PERMANENT) = UPPER('Y');

            V_contracotr_id cst_id_type;
        BEGIN

            FOR rec IN cursor_contract_name LOOP

                V_contracotr_id := rec.fk2_contractor_id;

                SELECT V_contracotr_id INTO V_cursor_contracotr_id FROM DUAL;

                dbms_output.put_line('cst_username : '||cst_username||'  V_contracotr_id :'||V_contracotr_id);


            END LOOP;

            PIPE ROW (V_cursor_contracotr_id);
            RETURN;
        END fnc_get_contractor_id;
    END;
    /
```

In the line

```
V_contracotr_id := rec.fk2_contractor_id;
```

It gives the error "inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got NUMBER" when the column selected by the cursor is of NUMBER type.

```
FK2_CONTRACTOR_ID   NUMBER
```

Comment: Personally, I would return a reference cursor, instead of a table.  That way, you aren't doing twice the work, once in the pl/sql and once on the materialized view.

Comment: is it of the type sys_refcursor?

Comment: The work is the same with refcursor proc or a table function. The benefit of the table function is that the result set can be further manipulated in SQL, even joined to other tables or other TFNs. Makes it easier to re-use acorss applications and to modularize complex logic.

Comment: Is this just an example? You don't need a `RECORD` type for just a single attribute. Do `TYPE cst_id_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER(10);` instead. In this case the column name is `COLUMN_VALUE`

Comment: yes this is an exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
        out_rec cst_record;

        CURSOR C1 IS
        SELECT ...;

  BEGIN

    open c1;
    LOOP
    FETCH c1 INTO out_rec;

  exit when c1%notfound;

    PIPE ROW(out_rec);

  END LOOP;

  close c1;

  RETURN;

END fnc_get_contractor_id;
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_contrator_of_consultant AS

    TYPE cst_record IS RECORD(
       consultant_id NUMBER(10));

    TYPE cst_id_type IS TABLE OF cst_record;

    FUNCTION fnc_get_contractor_id(cst_username IN VARCHAR2)
        RETURN cst_id_type
        PIPELINED;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_contrator_of_consultant AS 
FUNCTION fnc_get_contractor_id(cst_username IN VARCHAR2 )
    RETURN cst_id_type
    PIPELINED IS    

    CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT plc.FK2_CONTRACTOR_ID
        FROM lds_consultant cons
        INNER JOIN lds_account acc on cons.consultant_id = acc.fk1_consultant_id 
        INNER JOIN lds_placement plc on acc.account_id = plc.FK1_ACCOUNT_ID
        WHERE UPPER(cons.USERNAME) = UPPER(cst_username)
        AND UPPER(plc.PLT_TO_PERMANENT) = UPPER('Y');

        out_rec cst_record;
    BEGIN

        open c1;
        LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO out_rec;

      exit when c1%notfound;

        PIPE ROW(out_rec);

      END LOOP;

      close c1;

      RETURN;

    END fnc_get_contractor_id;
END;
/
```

Comment: Im still getting the error  "expression 'V_CONTRACOTR_ID' in the INTO list is of
         wrong type". I even have the user-defined type same as the column selected by the cursor.

Comment: Try the code that I gave you. There is no "V_CONTRACOTR_ID" in it.

Comment: same error. I just renamed out_rect to "V_CONTRACTOR_ID".

Comment: Can you please paste the exact code you are executing now?

Comment: You need both types - record and table, and OUT_REC should be of the record type. Your RETURN is correct - table type.